Pytest in Tox - can't find tests, `ImportError`
I have a package with the current structure:
my_package
   |- pyproject.toml
   |- poetry.lock
   |- tox.ini
   |- my_package
   |  |- __init__.py
   |  |- my_package.py
   |- tests
      |- test_my_package.py

pyproject.toml is configured for pytest as such:
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
addopts = [
    "--import-mode=importlib",
]
testpaths = [
    "tests",
]

tox.ini has the following configuration, as per the first use case in the example of poetry's official documentation
[tox]
env_list =
    format
    py312

[testenv:format]
description = install black in a virtual environment and invoke it on the current folder
deps = black==22.3.0
skip_install = true
commands = black .

[testenv:py312]
deps =
    pytest
commands =
    pytest tests

Running pytest tests works perfectly fine, but when I run tox, I get ImportError while importing test module '~\Documents\repos\my_package\tests\test_my_package.py - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named tests
I've tried configuring tox & pytest with testpaths (pytest works perfectly fine without this configuration). I also tried adding an __init__.py to the directory tests.
What am I missing here?
As a sidenote, I tried the second use case in the Poetry docs - that worked to run the tests but it doesn't run the tests in an virtual environment separate to my working venv, and it also uninstalls any optional packages I need for generating documentation & so on.

The solution was to add __init__.py in all directories under test.
